# On determining a function given a certain parametrization of a point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, curves

Imagine we have a parametrization of a particle in 2D space like this

http://i.minus.com/iXL64EfdJe6w5.gif

How do we go about finding an explicit way to express these functions ($f(x)$ and $g(x)$) based on the angle $a$ (see the figure below)? (In the same way we get to express $\sin$ and $\cos$ in the unit circle using many ways)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UH0F.png

And what field of maths can answer those questions? (I guess it's diff. geometry) Can we always find explicit ways to express these functions?

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! What have you tried so far? This problem is probably quite messy to solve, but it might be a good idea to compute the equation for the center of the large rotating circle, then use it to compute an equation for the center of the smaller one, and so on.

Comment: @MoseWintner Thanks. I have no idea on how to to approach the problem, I haven't studied diff.geo. yet. If it can be solved using only algebra-precalc methods then I'm fully open to hints.

Comment: I don't think you need anything fancy like differential geometry for this--you will probably only need calculus. Try first parametrizing the center of the large circle, and parametrizing a point on the large circle.

Comment: I don't know calculus yet.

Comment: Made on Java? What is the ratio of the three circles' radii ? The animation is too fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this it'll be extremely useful to know how to add and subtract vectors, and how to multiply them by scalars. If you don't know how to do this yet, it's not hard, and now is a great time to learn!

Let's order the circles in descending order of size with radii $R_0>R_1>R_2>R_3$. Suppose circle $i$ makes one rotation around its containing circle every $2\pi\omega_i$ time units.

Let $\vec{c}_i(t)$ be the location of circle $i$'s center at time $t$.

It's not hard to see that $\vec{c}_1(t)=(R_0-R_1)(\cos(\omega_1 t),\sin(\omega_1 t))$, since the center of the larger circle just traces out another circle of radius $R_0-R_1$.

It's also not terribly hard to see that $$\vec{c}_2(t)=\vec{c}_1(t) + (R_2-R_1)(\cos(\omega_2 t), \sin(\omega_2 t))$$ and

$$\vec{c}_3(t)=\vec{c}_2(t) + (R_3-R_2)(\cos(\omega_3 t), \sin(\omega_3 t))$$.

Back-substituting gives us a nice parametrization of $\vec{c}_3(t)$, which is what we were after.

Comment: thanks, it will take me some time to fully comprehend the post but it contains the necessary